# Representing Higher-Order Functors as Containers in Coq

Tags: containers, coq, functor

Following [this](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~tom.schrijvers/Research/papers/haskell2014.pdf) approach, I'm trying to model functional programs using effect handlers in Coq, based on an implementation in Haskell. There are two approaches presented in the paper:

- Effect syntax is represented as a functor and combined with the free monad.

```
    data Prog sig a = Return a | Op (sig (Prog sig a))
```

Due to the termination check not liking non-strictly positive definitions, this data type can't be defined directly. However, containers can be used to represent strictly-positive functors, as described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08059.pdf). This approach works but since I need to model a scoped effect that requires explicit scoping syntax, mismatched begin/end tags are possible. For reasoning about programs, this is not ideal.

- The second approach uses higher-order functors, i.e. the following data type.

```
    data Prog sig a = Return a | Op (sig (Prog sig) a)
```

Now sig has the type (* -> *) -> * -> *. The data type can't be defined in Coq for the same reasons as before. I'm looking for ways to model this data type, so that I can implement scoped effects without explicit scoping tags.

My attempts of defining a container for higher-order functors have not been fruitful and I can't find anything about this topic. I'm thankful for pointers in the right direction and helpful comments.

Edit: One example of scoped syntax from the paper that I would like to represent is the following data type for exceptions.

```
data HExc e m a = Throw′ e | forall x. Catch′ (m x) (e -> m x) (x -> m a)
```

Edit2: I have merged the suggested idea with my approach.

```
Inductive Ext Shape (Pos : Shape -> Type -> Type -> Type) (F : Type -> Type) A :=
  ext : forall s, (forall X, Pos s A X -> F X) -> Ext Shape Pos F A.

Class HContainer (H : (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type):=
  {
    Shape   : Type;
    Pos     : Shape -> Type -> Type -> Type;
    to      : forall M A, Ext Shape Pos M A -> H M A;
    from    : forall M A, H M A -> Ext Shape Pos M A;
    to_from : forall M A (fx : H M A), @to M A (@from M A fx) = fx;
    from_to : forall M A (e : Ext Shape Pos M A), @from M A (@to M A e) = e
  }.

Section Free.
  Variable H : (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type.

  Inductive Free (HC__F : HContainer H) A :=
  | pure : A -> Free HC__F A
  | impure : Ext Shape Pos (Free HC__F) A -> Free HC__F A.
End Free.
```

The code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/nbun/3e3f2198eae099c8409bf41c04271b3c). The Lambda Calculus example works and I can prove that the container representation is isomorphic to the data type.
I have tried to to the same for a simplified version of the exception handler data type but it does not fit the container representation.

Defining a smart constructor does not work, either. In Haskell, the constructor works by applying `Catch'` to a program where an exception may occur and a continuation, which is empty in the beginning.

```
catch :: (HExc <: sig) => Prog sig a -> Prog sig a
catch p = inject (Catch' p return)
```

The main issue I see in the Coq implementation is that the shape needs to be parameterized over a functor, which leads to all sorts of problems.

Comment: Have you seen the Modular Meta Theory a la Carte paper? I believe they tackle exactly this problem, although I’ve never really understood their solution.

Comment: I did not know about the paper, thanks. While it looks interesting, I'm not sure if this is the same problem I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer gives more intuition about how to derive containers from functors than my previous one. I'm taking quite a different angle, so I'm making a new answer instead of revising the old one.

## Simple recursive types

Let's consider a simple recursive type first to understand non-parametric containers, and for comparison with the parameterized generalization. Lambda calculus, without caring about scopes, is given by the following functor:

```
Inductive LC_F (t : Type) : Type :=
| App : t -> t -> LC_F t
| Lam : t -> LC_F t
.
```

There are two pieces of information we can learn from this type:

- The *shape* tells us about the constructors (`App`, `Lam`), and potentially also auxiliary data not relevant to the recursive nature of the syntax (none here). There are two constructors, so the shape has two values. `Shape := App_S | Lam_S` (`bool` also works, but declaring shapes as standalone inductive types is cheap, and named constructors also double as documentation.)
- For every shape (i.e., constructor), the *position* tells us about recursive occurences of syntax in that constructor. `App` contains two subterms, hence we can define their two positions as booleans; `Lam` contains one subterm, hence its position is a unit. One could also make `Pos (s : Shape)` an indexed inductive type, but that is a pain to program with (just try).

```
(* Lambda calculus *)
Inductive ShapeLC :=
| App_S    (* The shape   App _ _ *)
| Lam_S    (* The shape   Lam _ *)
.

Definition PosLC s :=
  match s with
  | App_S => bool
  | Lam_S => unit
  end.
```

## Parameterized recursive types

Now, properly scoped lambda calculus:

```
Inductive LC_F (f : Type -> Type) (a : Type) : Type :=
| App : f a -> f a -> LC_F a
| Lam : f (unit + a) -> LC_F a
.
```

In this case, we can still reuse the `Shape` and `Pos` data from before. But this functor encodes one more piece of information: how each position changes the type parameter `a`. I call this parameter the context (`Ctx`).

```
Definition CtxLC (s : ShapeLC) : PosLC s -> Type -> Type :=
  match s with
  | App_S => fun _ a => a  (* subterms of App reuse the same context *)
  | Lam_S => fun _ a => unit + a  (* Lam introduces one variable in the context of its subterm *)
  end.
```

This container `(ShapeLC, PosLC, CtxLC)` is related to the functor `LC_F` by an isomorphism: between the sigma `{ s : ShapeLC & forall p : PosLC s, f (CtxLC s p a) }` and `LC_F a`. In particular, note how the function `y : forall p, f (CtxLC s p)` tells you exactly how to fill the shape `s = App_S` or `s = Lam_S` to construct a value `App (y true) (y false) : LC_F a` or `Lam (y tt) : LC_F a`.

My previous representation encoded `Ctx` in some additional type indices of `Pos`. The representations are equivalent, but this one here looks tidier.

## Exception handler calculus

We'll consider just the `Catch` constructor. It has four fields: a type `X`, the main computation (which returns an `X`), an exception handler (which also recovers an `X`), and a continuation (consuming the `X`).

```
Inductive Exc_F (E : Type) (F : Type -> Type) (A : Type) :=
| ccatch : forall X, F X -> (E -> F X) -> (X -> F A) -> Exc_F E F A.
```

The shape is a single constructor, but you must include `X`. Essentially, look at all the fields (possibly unfolding nested inductive types), and keep all the data that doesn't mention `F`, that's your shape.

```
Inductive ShapeExc :=
| ccatch_S (X : Type)     (* The shape   ccatch X _ (fun e => _) (fun x => _) *)
.
(* equivalently, Definition ShapeExc := Type. *)
```

The position type lists all the ways to get an `F` out of an `Exc_F` of the corresponding shape. In particular, a position contains the arguments to apply functions with, and possibly any data to resolve branching of any other sort. In particular, you need to know the exception type to store exceptions for the handler.

```
Inductive PosExc (E : Type) (s : ShapeExc) : Type :=
| main_pos                      (* F X *)
| handle_pos (e : E)            (* E -> F X *)
| continue_pos (x : getX s)     (* X -> F A *)
.

(* The function getX takes the type X contained in a ShapeExc value, by pattern-matching: getX (ccatch_S X) := X. *)
```

Finally, for each position, you need to decide how the context changes, i.e., whether you're now computing an `X` or an `A`:

```
Definition Ctx (E : Type) (s : ShapeExc) (p : PosExc E s) : Type -> Type :=
  match p with
  | main_pos | handle_pos _ => fun _ => getX s
  | continue_pos _ => fun A => A
  end.
```

Using the conventions from [your code](https://gist.github.com/nbun/3e3f2198eae099c8409bf41c04271b3c), you can then encode the `Catch` constructor as follows:

```
Definition Catch' {E X A}
           (m : Free (C__Exc E) X)
           (h : E -> Free (C__Exc E) X)
           (k : X -> Free (C__Exc E) A) : Free (C__Exc E) A :=
  impure (@ext (C__Exc E) (Free (C__Exc E)) A (ccatch_S X) (fun p =>
    match p with
    | main_pos => m
    | handle_pos e => h e
    | continue_pos x => k x
    end)).

(* I had problems with type inference for some reason, hence @ext is explicitly applied *)
```

Full gist https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/6e7fb880c14207eda5fc6a5c06ef3522

Comment: This is a really helpful answer and detailed walk-through (and, again, a good example of why I like the Coq/FP-community so much ; )). Is there any citable publication/reference you've read/wrote that gives similar details to the the usage of containers for more complicated functors? Since you named your first gist "FreeIndexedMonad", I was wondering if [Indexed Containers](http://strictlypositive.org/indexed-containers.pdf) are related? After a first glance I couldn't tell if they are also capable of handling similar examples to the one above.

Comment: Excellent answer, I really appreciate your effort. I'm still in the process of adapting my code base to the higher-order approach but so far it looks very promising.

Comment: Thanks! @ichistmeinname This paper is indeed closely related! The two presentations here and in the paper are basically equivalent. They actually represent higher-order functors `(I -> Type) -> (O -> Type)` and you can generalize `Ctx s : Pos s -> Type -> Type` to `Ctx s : Pos s -> O -> I` to do the same here. Sadly I don't know any publication to point to offhand otherwise.

Comment: I named my file `FreeIndexedMonad` but after thinking about it more, I'm not sure it generates much monadic structure at all for free. `Ret` provides an intuitive base case for many constructions, but to define substitution we need to look inside the container/functor to see how `Ctx` behaves.

Comment: So, do you think that `Free` based on `HOContainer` is not a monadic structure anymore? The free monad mentioned in the [paper above](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~tom.schrijvers/Research/papers/haskell2014.pdf) is based on a higher-order functor and still a monad, so my intuition was that we have the same situation for `Free` based on `HContainer`.

Comment: Or a different but related question: a representation using `Ext` should be isomorphic to something like `Catch`. `Catch` is a higher-order functor and we can define a function `emap :: (F A -> F B) -> H F A -> H F B`. That is, we should be able to define such a function for `Ext` as well, or shouldn't we?

Comment: My thought was that on first-order syntax, every container defines a functor, then `Prog`/`Free` takes every functor to a monad, so there is a simple function from containers to monads. On higher-order syntax, containers still define (higher-order) functors (via `Ext`), but `Prog` requires more structure than that.

Comment: `emap` gives a sufficient condition, and seems satisfactory in many situations, but 1) it doesn't seem we can have an instance for lambda calculus `LC_F`, so `emap` may be a bit too strong, 2) the need for such extra constraints suggests that the definition of higher-order containers given here is too loose in some way.

Comment: Another obstacle I came across is the definition of effectful, recursive data structures for a specific container, like [this](https://gist.github.com/nbun/5648f44c8274ec48fe4e59fed0feb9b3). The definition leads to an error due to non-strict occurrence of `List`, which makes sense since there is no guarantee what F might do with its argument in the definition of Ext. Representing F as a container doesn't seem viable because then `Free` would need to be represented as a container itself. It seems to me that there is no way around this?

Answer (score 2):

The main trick in the "first-order" free monad encoding is to encode a functor `F : Type -> Type` as a container, which is essentially a dependent pair `{ Shape : Type ; Pos : Shape -> Type }`, so that, for all `a`, the type `F a` is isomorphic to the sigma type `{ s : Shape & Pos s -> a }`.

Taking this idea further,  we can encode a higher-order functor `F : (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)` as a container `{ Shape : Type & Pos : Shape -> Type -> (Type -> Type) }`, so that, for all `f` and `a`, `F f a` is isomorphic to `{ s : Shape & forall x : Type, Pos s a x -> f x }`.

I don't quite understand what the extra `Type` parameter in `Pos` is doing there, but It Works™, at least to the point that you can construct some lambda calculus terms in the resulting type.

For example, the lambda calculus syntax functor:

```
Inductive LC_F (f : Type -> Type) (a : Type) : Type :=
| App : f a -> f a -> LC_F a
| Lam : f (unit + a) -> LC_F a
.
```

is represented by the container `(Shape, Pos)` defined as:

```
(* LC container *)

Shape : Type := bool; (* Two values in bool = two constructors in LC_F *)
Pos (b : bool) : Type -> (Type -> Type) :=
         match b with
         | true => App_F
         | false => Lam_F
         end;
```

where `App_F` and `Lam_F` are given by:

```
Inductive App_F (a : Type) : TyCon :=
| App_ (b : bool) : App_F a a
.

Inductive Lam_F (a : Type) : TyCon :=
| Lam_ : Lam_F a (unit + a)
.
```

Then the free-like monad `Prog` (implicitly parameterized by `(Shape, Pos)`) is given by:

```
Inductive Prog (a : Type) : Type :=
| Ret : a -> Prog a
| Op (s : Shape) : (forall b, Pos s a b -> Prog b) -> Prog a
.
```

Having defined some boilerplate, you can write the following example:

```
(* \f x -> f x x *)
Definition omega {a} : LC a :=
  Lam (* f *) (Lam (* x *)
    (let f := Ret (inr (inl tt)) in
     let x := Ret (inl tt) in
     App (App f x) x)).
```

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/5485709c4594b836113736626070f488

Comment: Have you intentionally written `s : bool` in `{ s : bool & forall x : Type, Pos b a x -> f x }`? I do not see why this needs to be `bool` and not a `s : Shape` as for the first-order version. Additionally, I guess the `b` in `Pos b a x` is supposed to be an `s`, right?

Comment: Indeed, that was a copy-paste mistake!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I merged your idea with my implementation and was able to prove that it works for the Lambda Calculus example. However, I am not able to represent a more complex exception handler type. I have added the code for a simplified version of the data type to my original post. Do you have an idea if this can be fixed?